# sails session writing bug

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using sails 0.10.4 and stumbled with one pretty annoying bug. When user logs in I write his data into the `req.session.user` then in policies I can retrieve his data such as his role, password etc. But the `req.session.user` becomes `undefined` when I go out of the `login` action. Do you have any ideas how to handle this? Here's the code:

 api/controllers/User.js :

```
module.exports = {
  login: function (req, res) {
    Users.findOneByEmail(req.param('email'))
      .exec(function (err, user) {
        if ((err) || (!user)) {
          res.send({
            error: 'User not found'
          });
          return;
        }
        if (!passwordHash.verify(req.param('password'), user.password)) {
          res.send({
            error: 'Incorrect passwpord'
          });
          return;
        }
        req.session.user = user;//I write user into the session
        res.send({
          user: user
        });
      });
  }
}
```

api/policies/isLoggedIn.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.authentication) {
    var credentials = JSON.parse(req.headers.authentication);
    if(req.session.user.login === credentials.login)//User doesn't exist in session
      return next();
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show some code, such as your login controller and your policy

Comment: I've updated it. And in policy file the session object doesn't include user.

Comment: does console.log(req.session.user) give undefined for isLoggedIn?

Comment: Yes. It worked well at 0.10-rc7. I think maybe something need to be configured in order to work.

Comment: This started happening immediately after upgrading?  No other changes?  So far we haven't seen any other reports of sessions being dropped.  Are you using built-in memory sessions, or storing on Mongo or Redis?

Comment: Hi! I can't track it now because I didn't saw when it happened. But it was on the same day when I upgraded sails. I'm using mongo adapter.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you're using Mongo to store the sessions? Like in **config/session.js**, you have `adapter: 'mongo'`?

Answer (score 0):

In a testing environment , this issue can happen when testing with Supertest and not defining an agent

```
var agent = request.agent(app);
agent.post('/api/login',{email:'foo@bar.com',password:'foobar})
.end(function(err,res){...; done();});
```

It is the correct way to work with sessions, simply using `request.post` would not work as it would reinit the session variable as soon as the response is sent, even if we are chaining requests inside the same test.

Learnt it the hard way, so I hope it can help some lost developper.